# File not getting loaded from target\test-classes\ even though it is available there

Tags: java, eclipse, file, junit, anypoint-studio

I'm trying to load a file for my test case inside the actual class. It is able to find the path as 'target\test-classes\abc.txt' but when I try to load it is failing. The same thing is working for my colleagues. Is this any issue of my eclipse. Below is the code

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("abc.txt").getFile());
if (file.exists())
{
}
```

'file.exists' is always 'false' even though the file is available. I have updated this with my pom.xml file also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8
        </project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <mule.version>3.9.0</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.7</mule.tools.version>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/sites/jacoco/jacoco.exec
        </sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <jacoco.output.path>target/sites/jacoco/</jacoco.output.path>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                    <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-transport-amqp</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-anypoint-mq</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                    </inclusions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0.1254</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <append>true</append>
                    <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                    <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</dataFile>
                    <outputDirectory>${jacoco.output.path}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-db</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your project configuration. If this is a Maven project, please show your `pom.xml` file so others can help you. And also tell where the code (in `src/test/java`, right?) and `abc.txt` (should be probably in `src/test/resources`) are placed.

Comment: If pom.xml is an issue everyone should face it. But only i'm facing this issue not other team mates.

Comment: Well, it could be that you do something different than your colleagues. One needs to know the `pom.xml` file and know where the files are located to be able to tell what's going wrong here. A common mistake here is to put the `abc.txt` file in `src/test/java` or in `src/main/resources` instead of in `src/test/resources`.

Comment: Where are you trying to load it, in application code or in a test? Is there an error?

Comment: I'm trying to load in application code via test case. There is no error. The file absolute path is coming correctly and that path even has the file.

Comment: One more thing is like if I load the file from my test class it loading. But if i pass the file name to my original class there it path is loading correctly but even though the file is available it is not able to pick it

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand it. If the file is loaded correctly, what line in the code is not working exactly? Do you mean reading the contents?

Comment: The file is not loaded the path is loaded correctly but the file.exists() results false even though the file is present.

Comment: > One more thing is like if I load the file from my test class it loading. But if i pass the file name to my original class there it path is loading correctly but even though the file is available it is not able to pick it 
Do you mean in the test the file exists, but in the main source it is not?

Comment: the file is available. Imagine I'm using `new File(classLoader.getResource("abc.txt").getFile());` in ABCTest.java it is executing. Same line in ABC.java it is not executing. But when printing `file.getAbsolutePath()` in ABC.java, it is coming correctly as target\test-classes\abc.txt.